# "Running /scripts/init-premount" delays ubuntu 20.04.3 boot

Tags: boot

When I boot my computer it is always stuck for ca 2 minutes on motherboard logo screen. There is a loading indicator but no more explaination. I pressed <kbd>Ctr</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd> to open to command line and saw this. "Begin: Running /scripts/init-premount". I found the folder init-premount ("/etc/initramfs-tools/scripts/init-premount") but it is empty. After the time is up (I have not seen "done" coming up at the end of the line as the "loading essential driver" line has). I have tried to:

1. Replace `RESUME=UUID=xxx` with `RESUME=none` (with sudo update grub)
2. Edit /etc/default/grub. I set `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="noresume"`

I don't know why the script is taking so long to run. Maybe it doesn't run the script it is just looking for it and the script just doesn't exist. I have no idea though.

This is what <kbd>Ctr</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd> looks like:

[image: Screen picture]

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when the boot partition UUID changes.

Need to update `initramfs` in addition to GRUB:

1. `sudo update-initramfs -u`
2. `sudo update-grub`

---

Note: `update-initramfs` is part of `initramfs-tools` package.